# How can I map based on objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two kinds of objects in `@results` (i.e. `@results = @videos + @artists`).

I'm trying to do, pseudo code:

```
@results.map(&:title || &:first_name)
```

A video has a title column, but artist does not. How do I make this work?

I could go into an each loop, but looking for a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to find the right method, I would create a common interface which I can call from anywhere.

Example(I'm using a method called "name", but you may choose another name):

The Video class will have the "name" method, like this:

```
class Video
  def name
    self.title
  end
end
```

And with the Artist class, I would do the same, but with the "first_name" method:

```
class Artist
  def name
    self.first_name
  end
end
```

Them, you can use the same method(name) on the map block:

```
@results.map(&:name)
```

Comment: Since `@results` is an array of different classes, I +1'd this answer because you should have something you can call on every instance in the `@results` array that will return what you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
@results.map{|x| 
  x.title if x.respond_to?('title')
  x.first_name if x.respond_to?('first_name')
}
```

Comment: Nah, that won't work. It will return `first_name` or `nil`, but never `title`.

Comment: it would return title if the object has a method called `title` independent from its datatype. It could be nil, string, integer,...

Comment: Would you provide a code snippet with a demonstration of this?

Comment: it works I used it several times if you want to prevent nil values you can add a `.nil?`method to handel these cases. Here the descriptioon of what respond_to? does: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F

Comment: No, you don't understand. `title` will never be returned by this code. Its result is ignored.

Comment: This works : `@results.collect{|x| 
  (x.title if x.respond_to?('title')) || 
  (x.first_name if x.respond_to?('first_name'))
}`